# Assigning 2d dynamic row to 1d array

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to assign ith row values of 2d array to 1d array. Those arrays are created dynamically. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define FRAC 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i, j;
    double **A, *B;

    A=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        A[i]=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
    }

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            A[i][j]=i*j/FRAC;
        }
    }

    B=A[0];

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%f\n",B[i]);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

When B is printed, all the values are shown as 0.0000. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your loop:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        A[i][j]=i*j/FRAC;
    }
}
```

You'll see that every element in `A[0]` involves a multiplication by `i == 0` so the your `B` will be all zero.

If you assign `B = A[1]` and force the computation into floating point mode by defining `FRAC` to `10.0` (or by adding explicit casts), you'll see something more interesting from your `printf` loop.

And, while I'm here, please don't cast the return value from `malloc`, it is not necessary and it often hides mistakes. You're also not allocating `A` properly, you should be doing `A = malloc(sizeof(double *) * N)`; lucky for you, `double` is almost always at least as big as a pointer.

This modified version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define FRAC 10.0   /* CHANGED */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    double **A, *B;

    A = malloc(sizeof(double *) * N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            /* This is floating point now that FRAC is 10.0 */
            A[i][j]= i * j / FRAC;
        }
    }

    B = A[1];   /* A[0] is all 0.0 so we'll look at A[1] instead. */
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%f\n", B[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Produce the following (which is more interesting and instructive than a bunch of zeros):

```
0.000000
0.100000
0.200000
0.300000
0.400000
0.500000
0.600000
0.700000
0.800000
0.900000
```

Comment: i am really embarrassed atm :) i tried to figure it out for hours. thank you sir!

Comment: Thank you for your tips to allocate memory. I have to improve myself on memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Both `i*j` and `FRAC` are integers, and in C, dividing two integers results in an integer, discarding any decimals you would normally have.

Change `FRAC` to explicitly be a floating-point value, e.g. by using `10.0` instead of `10`.